# How to prevent mail from Wordpress website from being flagged as spam on Exchange online server

Tags: wordpress, exchange-server, email

I have a website; let's call it abc.com. It's e-mail is handled by Office365. I recently migrated it from a Sharepoint environment to a different webhost (GoDaddy). I have tried using the WP Mail SMTP plugin option to send e-mails, but it fails to send.

My settings are:

```
smtp: smtp.office365.com
port: 587
encryption: use TLS
authentication: use smtp
```

Sending fails with the error:

```
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
```

Using the default wp mail with the settings below works to send to e-mail addresses *outside* the domain, but messages get flagged as spam on addresses within the domain.

```
header = 'From: '.get_option('blogname').' <wordpress@abc.com>'
```

I have e-mail routing set to Remote Mail Exchanger. I've tried adding the address `wordpress@abc.com` to Exchange's allowed list/whitelist, and I even tried adding the host IP to trusted IPs on the server - but it still doesn't work.

Comment: How did you go with this @GotaloveCode?

Comment: I ended up using the default wp mail.On the client o365 admin I added the email address to the whitelist. Made the mail rule priority over the default spam filter rule.I even went a step further to whitelist the IP but that's overkill I think. @TimMalone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the default wp mail.On the client o365 admin I added the email address to the whitelist. Made the mail rule priority over the default spam filter rule.I even went a step further to whitelist the IP but that's overkill I think.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, GoDaddy do **not** let you send mail to external SMTP providers. If you're not able to choose another host (which I'd recommend if you can!), you'll need to use wp mail and send all mail to a local address at the same domain, hosted with GoDaddy.

If you wanted to, you could then set up an alias to send it elsewhere.

There's some more background on this over at [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org), such as [this thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/not-able-to-send-on-godaddy-or-gmail?replies=9) and [this thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/smtp-connect-failed?replies=33).

**EDIT**

Just realised that the [Postman SMTP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/) claims it can get around GoDaddy's filtering using HTTPS:

> "Even hosts that block the standard SMTP ports, like GoDaddy or Bluehost, can't stop your email as Postman can deliver via HTTPS if it can't use SMTP."

So maybe give that plugin a go instead. :)

Comment: my problem isn't really sending mail.It is mail from the website contact form being flagged as spam on the email accounts on exchange.Also the domain is hosted elsewhere but the web files are hosted on go daddy.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you'll find it's the same problem - if you give Postman a try does it resolve the marking as spam?

Comment: Re the domain being hosted elsewhere, this can mean many things, but I'm assuming you mean domain registration (or maybe you mean DNS). Domain registration will have no bearing on mail, but potentially looking at an SPF record could help with the spam issue...

Comment: looking at the anwer by awtx on https://wordpress.org/support/topic/smtp-connect-failed/page/2?replies=24 he says that godaddy ignores all smtp attempts and reroutes to use their own mail server.Postman suggests I use mandrill which is a paid subscription.Am looking to use the resources already allocated exchange and godaddy hosting.

Comment: Also how do I add the SPF record domain hosting is done on some server I have no access to.I have access to o365 and godaddy. @Tim

Comment: Re SPF record - you'll need access to wherever DNS is hosted to change that